Hibernate and UNNEST - Memory leak over time due to cache
We are using hibernate in our java service which handles massive amount of incoming messages from SQS, processing them and accordingly insert/update/delete from Postgres DB.
We've found out that after a while our pod killing our service due to memory growth.
After investigating, I've found that I have a ConcurrentHashMap that grows and grows with time of handling messages. Checking the latest nodes shows that there are many types of value org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.ArrayJdbcType#.....
In the service we do not use simple org.springframework.data.repository.Repository methods but custom query to accelerate our DB process.
Our queries look like this:
@Modifying
@Query(value =
"""
INSERT INTO my_table (id, key, name)
SELECT id, key, name
FROM UNNEST(:ids\\:\\:uuid[], :keys\\:\\:varchar[], :names\\:\\:varchar[])
"""
, nativeQuery = true)
void insertData(UUID[] ids, String[] keys, String[] names);

or updates likes those, or deletion and more and more. This was just example for simplifying.
I'm sure that those queries are the reason for hibernate to create the typeDescriptors but ..

Is this growth of memory normal ?
Is there a way to prevent it ?
Is there a better way to perform those kind of queries from both memory and efficiency in DB and in the service ?
I've started to create a UserType to declare my parameter that will hold (id,key,name) but struggeling with it a lot and i'm not sure if it will work at all. Coult it help by maybe reusing a type ?
I'm open for any other suggestions to my problem.

Thanks!
-- UPDATE --
I've created a topic in hibernate, they found the bug and fixed it. What is left is to wait to version 6.6.2.Final..

What is a lot of memory? On physical hardware a decent-sized Java application can easily use 8G or more, but in pods people seldom provision that much. Log garbage collections and make sure that Java knows how much memory it has to play with and adapts. With that said, for native SQL you can always drop down to JDBC with prepared statements. That will be more efficient for sure.

The pod is growing to 1.8Gb and then restarts. But I've checked in my computer with a heap of 150mb for the tests, to see if the GC is freeing some memory, but it does not.

Well, gc will not free memory if it is used. 1.8G is not much for a Java application that handles massive amounts of messages - perhaps you should simply increase the limit? But otherwise plain JDBC is not so hard and will not have this issue.

Increasing the memory will just push my problem further. Anyway, I've updated my post - hibernate found the bug and fixed it. so i will skip at the moment fighting with the UserType approach.

I think that one way to prevent the growing ConcurrentHashMap is to not use Hibernate, but go one step down in abstractions and use Spring's JdbcTemplate.
JdbcTemplate should be available as bean (if not, you can add spring-boot-starter-jdbc to your pom.xml) which you can inject into a separate repository-bean. Then you can use the batchUpdate function to insert (and update/delete) many records.
In the example below I have also used the TransactionTemplate but you can replace that with the @Transactional annotation if you like. I have also used the PGobject class (from org.postgresql:postgresql) for the UUID-column, but there are also alternative solutions that do not require the PGobject class.
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

    public void addRecords(final int recordsAmount, final int batchSize) {
        var records = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        final var nowKey = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final var nowName = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(LocalDateTime.now());
        IntStream.range(0, recordsAmount).forEach(i -> {
            var r = new Object[3];
            r[0] = UUID.randomUUID();
            r[1] = i + "-" + nowKey;
            r[2] = i + "-" + nowName;
            records.add(r);
        });
        final String insertQuery = """
            insert into my_table (id, "key", name) values (?, ?, ?)
            """;
        int[][] updated = transactionTemplate.execute((TransactionStatus t) -> {
            return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                insertQuery, records, batchSize, 
                (PreparedStatement ps, Object[] r) -> {
                    var uuidObject = new PGobject();
                    uuidObject.setType("uuid");
                    uuidObject.setValue(r[0].toString());
                    ps.setObject(1, uuidObject);
                    ps.setString(2, (String) r[1]);
                    ps.setString(3, (String) r[2]);
                }
            );
        });
        log.info("Number of batches: {}", updated.length);
    }

You will need to read some (javadoc) documentation and experiment to figure out what kind of errors can be thrown (and when) and if you need to look into the updated return values.

You are all right regarding drop hibernate.. But sadly it is above my hands. And btw, I've updated my post - hibernate found the bug and fixed it. so i will skip at the moment fighting with the UserType approach - And no need at the moment to change the way we work, and just wait for a final version of hibernate. Thanks for the help!
